# merging graphql servers schemas

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql

I am trying to create a graphql microservice architecture and I want to be able to dynamically update my schemas with properties from other servers.

So for example I have a service `library` with this schema

```
type Query {
  movie: [Movie]
}

enum Status {
  IN_LIBRARY
  WISHLIST
}

type Movie {
  id: Int
  status: Status
}
```

And I want to extend the movie object with properties from a different service `tmdb` with the following schema

```
type Query {
  movie(filter: MovieFilter): [Movie]
}

type Movie {
  id: Int
  title: String
  tagline: String
  overview: String
  backdrop: String
  poster(width: Int): String
  budget: Int
  genre: [String]
  release(format: String): String
}
```

I've seen a couple of articles where two schemas are stiched sort of like this, but they always assume 2 remote graphql servers, whereas I want to query `tmdb` from `library` only when requested.

Is this at all possible?

My current setup for `library` looks like this:

```
  var app = express();
  app.use(
    "/graphql",
    graphqlHTTP(async (req, res, graphQLParams) => ({
      schema: buildSchema(fs.readFileSync("assets/schema.graphql", "utf8")),
      rootValue: await server(req, graphQLParams),
      graphiql: true
    }))
  );
```

Comment: "but they always assume 2 remote graphql servers"... So are you creating separate GraphQL services for these 2 schemas, exposing each as a separate endpoint and want to *delegate* the resolution of some fields in one to another? Or are you just trying to figure out how to split your single service into modules?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. I am creating 2 services and want to delegate the resolution of some fields in one to another.